# Web2py's port no of server from inside the application

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

How do I get the port no on the server (on which web2py app is deployed) from inside the web2py application (for ex. controller or module)?

I am using urllib to interact with another action inside the controller by doing this

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000%s?%s'%(URL('unregister_relationship.json'),urllib.urlencode(data))) 
response = json.loads(response.read())
```

but this needs port no to be known beforehand, I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The `URL()` helper takes `scheme` and `host` arguments to generate an absolute URL. Also, no need to use `urllib.urlencode` to generate the query string, as you can pass a dictionary as the `vars` argument:

```
urllib2.urlopen(URL('unregister_relationship.json', vars=data, scheme='http', host=True))
```

As an alternative, you might also consider using [JSON-RPC](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#JSONRPC) to allow the two apps to communicate.